# How to ensure that an IMG is displayed in the Reader Viewer?

Tags: html, css, safari, microsoft-edge, reader

I'm using the following HTML/CSS to display images of screenshots of my product:

```
<p>Review the following screenshots:</p>
<div>
<a href="images/pic1.png" target="_blank" title="Full size screenshot 1">
<img border="0" src="images/pic1.png" class="wbrdr"></a>
<a href="images/pic2.png" target="_blank" title="Full size screenshot 2">
<img border="0" src="images/pic2.png" class="wbrdr"></a>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
img.wbrdr
{
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;
    height: auto; 
    width: auto; 
    max-width: 200px; 
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

This works fine when the page is viewed normally, but for some reason when I tried to view it as a "Reader View" in Sarari in iOS, or as "Reading view" in Microsoft Edge:

[image]

My screenshot images were not used/displayed. (Although that worked in Firefox.)

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run the code you providing directly in Microsoft Edge and the Reading view icon is grey.

Then I add some other paragraphs and I find that the screenshot images can be displayed in Reading view in Microsoft Edge without being wrapped by `<div>`. You could try the following sample in Microsoft Edge:

```
<h2>A layout that is easy on the eyes</h2>
<p>Some Web articles require significant effort to read, because there is so much other content on the page. In contrast, the effect we were going for with reading view in IE 11 can almost be described as one of relief – the page should just feel good to look at. To that end, we gave attention to a few aspects of the layout that can make a difference, specifically aiming to get the right balance of column width, line height, and text size.</p>
<p>For example, because the user can change the font size in reading view it was important for the feature to adjust the line spacing too as the font got bigger. Other considerations were padding (white space) between columns, around images, and between paragraphs. The goal was for the page to feel clean and free of distractions, and this padding helps your eyes and brain quickly identify and distinguish the different elements of the article from each other, as well as provide cues for orienting your path through the text.</p>
<p>Review the following screenshots:</p>
<a href="images/pic1.png" target="_blank" title="Full size screenshot 1">
    <img border="0" src="images/pic1.png" class="wbrdr">
</a>
<a href="images/pic2.png" target="_blank" title="Full size screenshot 2">
    <img border="0" src="images/pic2.png" class="wbrdr">
</a>
```

Comment: Oh, wow. that's a really good find. Actually replacing <div> with <p> makes it work with iOS. But still not with Edge. For Edge I need to remove <div> completely, but then for some weird reason the reader in Edge puts my screenshots in quite weird places, like one in the beginning of the document. So I'm not sure what else it wants me to add there?

Comment: Do you mean Edge reading view put one image before the title? [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5dvm.png) at the beginning of the document. I also found this behavior. Actually Edge reading view will do this in every document, putting the first image at the beginning of the reading view, like a banner. I think it is by-design in Edge reading view and we can't control it.

Comment: Yeah, like that. In my case it's the very first thing on the left.

Comment: So what's the lesson from all this? Not to use <div> and <p> tags. But how would I group images together?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand "group images together". In reading view, the images are still together but just shown one by one. I think the reading view is designed showing images one by one which is convenient for users to read and concentrate.

Comment: So what you're _not understanding_ is that we should just forget about DIVs?

Comment: Oh, I see. I tested again and I found a strange thing. The images can be displayed in Edge reading view with `<div>` wrapping now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ckRd.gif.  I also tested in others' machines so I think it's not due to cache. You could check it in your side. If still can't wrap images with `<div>`, what about use `<section>` as an alternative? It can also work in my side.

Comment: You know I tried `<section>` earlier and it didn't work. There must be something in my HTML that confuses Edge.... I'll keep looking. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. You could come back if you find something or need more help.